# How to return http response after modifying header content type in python

Tags: python, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I am writing an controller endpoint in Python and I want to modify response code, content-text etc. How can I achieve it.

```
@http.route('/get/data/',methods=['GET','POST'],type="http",auth='public',csrf=False)
def  fetchSms(self,**kwargs):
    mydata = {"date":"2018-10-13T00:46:17.25Z"}
    return simplejson.dumps(mydata)
```

I have to return mydata to client after setting content-type="application/json" and response response code should be 200

Current Output:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: nginx/1.12.2

Date: Mon, 15 Oct 2018 16:57:49 GMT

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 192

Connection: keep-alive

Set-Cookie: session_id=43edf5hfgh436sdgdga9d7618deb74af7; Expires=Sun, 13-Jan-2019 16:57:49 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/

Comment: Which web framework are you using? You forgot to say in your question.

Comment: its odoo framework, not flask or django. Do we have any way to achieve without using any framework, using some python library?

Comment: I got this working, It was based on Odoo framework. return Response("TEST",content_type='application/json;charset=utf-8',status=200)

Comment: Great. To answer your question, no. The way to return a custom header or content type is largely dependant on the web framework you're using to write the code, as each framework will have a different syntax to do it.